# Compare 2 name field of 2 table and retrive id of name field that matching

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 table, 'accessories' and 'categories', in the first table i have more field 'name' es. 'DISPLAY FOR  APPLE I-PHONE 5S' and in second table 'name' es. 'iPhone 5S' and 'id_category' es. '140'.  I would retrive 'id_category' from second table where 'categories.name' is in 'accessories.name' . I try this but doesnt work!

```
$sql_selecet_cat = "SELECT id_category, name FROM categories LIMIT 10 ";
$results = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_selecet_cat);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    // output data of each row

     while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
         echo $rows['name'] . '</BR>'; //here retrive correctly all name

         $name_rec = $rows['name']; //output es.'iPhone 5S','iPhone 6','iPhone 7'etc..
         $id_rec = $rows['id_category']; //output es.'140','141','142'
         $name_rec = strtolower($name_rec); 


     }


}

$sql_selecet = "SELECT name FROM accessories LIMIT 20  ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_selecet);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['name'] . '</BR>'; //here retrive correctly all name 
        $name = $rows['name']; //output es.'DISPLAY FOR  APPLE IPHONE 5S', 'DISPLAY FOR  APPLE IPHONE 8', 'DISPLAY FOR  SAMSUNG S8'
        $name = strtolower($name);

 }
 }

if (strpos($name, $name_rec) !== FALSE) {

    echo $id_rec; //here retrive the first ten id_category in the table but dont match name
```

I set limit onli because there are 2000 record :)

I want match name of the two table and retrive correct 'id_category' of any accessories 'name'.

Can anyone say me where wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, shouldn't a simple Inner Join help you out? Can you please try- select id_category, categories.name
from categories inner join accessories on accessories.name = accessories.name limit 20;

Comment: Are $name_rec and $name arrays? Won't this just get the last result in the categories query and compare it to the last result in the accessories query? That could be a starting point for a debug?

Comment: Many thanks for reply. I try and reply you.